# How to implement Null checker in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, null-check

I'm learning Dart for the first time. I have learned the concept of exception handling, and I also learned that we can specify null checker, which edits a variable if it's value become null. I have shared the code that I got from my tutor.

```
void main()
{
   print("Enter two numbers: ");
   var num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
   var num2 = stdin.readLineSync();

   num1 ??= '0';
   num2 ??= '0';

   var input1 = int.parse(num1);
   var input2 = int.parse(num2);

   print("SUM = ${input1 + input2}");
}
```

After running this code, everything works fine, but whenever I try to give null values when it was told to input two numbers, the code crashes. I have heard that the code will crash if null values are parsed, so I tried to change the null values into '0'.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Crashes how?  What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you're inputing `'null'` into your keyboard to assign to the `num1` variable, correct?

If that's the case, you're not passing `null` to `num1`, instead you're passing `'null`' (`String`)

When you try to `int.parse('null')` it gives you an error because `.parse` doesn't know how to convert the String `'null'` into an `int`. You can use `int.tryParse(String)` instead. It returns `null` instead of throwing an exception when it cannot parse the String

Try this instead:

```
void main(){

   print("Enter two numbers: ");
   var num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
   var num2 = stdin.readLineSync();

   num1 ??= '0';
   num2 ??= '0';

   var input1 = int.tryParse(num1) ?? 0;
   var input2 = int.tryParse(num2) ?? 0;

   print("SUM = ${input1 + input2}");
}
```

Comment: First thing to say, I just pressed the "ENTER" key in my keyboard when asked to "Enter Two numbers" to create the null character, and that's what my tutor told me. That didn't worked for me.

Comment: Second thing, I tried your answer, but now it became an error. It tells that "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.".

Comment: Try this now, I've eddited the answer